# probability of having two boys in a family with two children, if probabilities of having boys and girls are different

Tags: probability

I first started with the assumption that probability of having boys and girls are same. I imagined I could get this using binomial probability distribution with number of trials=2, number of successes=2 and probability of success=0.5, which gives me probability of 1/4 for two boys. Here is where I got confused, since it doesn't matter in which order they had the children, only which gender they are. So considering all possible cases as BB, BG and GG and that they will be equiprobable, the correct answer for this case should be 1/3.

How do I get the probabilities of two boys from above if probability of having boys is say, p and having girls is (1-p)?

Comment: Your statement about $\frac13$ is wrong.  Flip two coins (or one coin twice) many times and count how often you get each pattern of heads and tails when ignoring which coin is which.

Comment: It is wrong to assume that BB , GG and GB have equal probabilities . Lets say $E_1$ be birth of first child and $E_2$ be birth of 2nd child. For  the Case GB either first child is girl or the 2nd child is girl which means it must have double the probability in respect to others.

Comment: the second case was given as the correct solution in a tests answer key and I rightly felt that something was wrong with their assumption. since birth of subsequent children is an independent event, i should stick with binomial probability distribution, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $4$ equally likely possibilities: BB, GG, BG, GB.  Your first calculation is correct.

When the probability of a boy is $p$, the probability of two boys is $p^2$.  We have two independent events.